# Unable to test mongodb insert functionality in node and jest

Tags: mongoose, jestjs

This is a function to connect to `mongodb` from `node`. The function is defined in `mongoUtils.js`.

```
dbConnectMongoose: async function (){
  
    console.log(`trying to connect to uri ${process.env.DATABASE_URL}`);
    const connection = await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
    console.log(`connected to Mongo.`);
      
    dbClient = connection.connections[0].client;
    var db;
    console.log(`got MongoClient: `); 
    try {
      db = dbClient.db(process.env.DATABASE);
      console.log(`connected to database ${db.databaseName}`);
      const collections = await db.collections();
      collections.forEach(c => {console.log(`got collection ${c.collectionName}`)})
    } catch(exception) {
      console.log(`something bad happened in dbconnect: ${exception}`);
    } finally {
      
     dbclass.db  = db;
     console.log(`db Class db is ${dbclass.db}`);
    }
  }
```

I call this function from a `api.test.js`

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const request = require("supertest")
const baseURL = "http://localhost:4000"
const baseURL2 = process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_TEST 
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
var Question = require('../schema/question');
var mongoUtils = require('../mongoUtils');

describe('insert', () => {
  let connection;
  let db;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    mongoUtils.dbConnectMongoose();
    db = mongoUtils.getDb();
    console.log(`db in app is ${db}`)
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    console.log("TBD - close conn")
  });

  it('should insert a question', async () => {
    q = Question({
      description: "some description",
      hints: ["hint1", "hint2"],
      topic: 'area'
    });
    q.save()
    .then ((result) => {
      console.log(`added question ${result}`);
    })
    .catch ( (err)=>{
      console.log(`error in adding question: ${err}`);
    });
  });
});
```

When I run `npm test` (`test` being defined as `"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=10000"`), I get the following error:

```
 ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api.test.js.        
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$getAllSubdocs (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3551:37)
      at _getPathsToValidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2641:23)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$__validate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2861:23)
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:497:25
C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206                                                                                                                          
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +                                                  
          ^                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                               
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.createClient (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:738:34)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:404:15)
    at Object.dbConnectMongoose (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\mongoUtils.js:21:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\test\api.test.js:17:16)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:300:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:233:10)
    at _callCircusHook (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:280:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:94:7)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:120:9)
    at run (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:70:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:444:34) 
    at Object.worker (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\testWorker.js:106:12)

Node.js v18.16.1

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api.test.js.        

      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$getAllSubdocs (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3551:37)
      at _getPathsToValidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2641:23)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$__validate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2861:23)
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:497:25
C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206                                                                                                                          
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +                                                  
          ^                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                               
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.createClient (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:738:34)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:404:15)
    at Object.dbConnectMongoose (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\mongoUtils.js:21:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\test\api.test.js:17:16)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:300:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:233:10)
    at _callCircusHook (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:280:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:94:7)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:120:9)
    at run (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:70:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:444:34) 
    at Object.worker (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\testWorker.js:106:12)

Node.js v18.16.1

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api.test.js.        

      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$getAllSubdocs (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3551:37)
      at _getPathsToValidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2641:23)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$__validate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2861:23)
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:497:25
C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
          ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.createClient (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:738:34)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:404:15)
    at Object.dbConnectMongoose (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\mongoUtils.js:21:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\test\api.test.js:17:16)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:300:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:233:10)
    at _callCircusHook (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:280:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:94:7)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:120:9)
    at run (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:70:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:444:34) 
    at Object.worker (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\testWorker.js:106:12)

Node.js v18.16.1

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api.test.js.        

      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$getAllSubdocs (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3551:37)
      at _getPathsToValidate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2641:23)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Document.$__validate (node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2861:23)
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:497:25
C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
          ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.createClient (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\connection.js:206:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:738:34)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:404:15)
    at Object.dbConnectMongoose (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\mongoUtils.js:21:39)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\test\api.test.js:17:16)
    at Promise.then.completed (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:300:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\utils.js:233:10)
    at _callCircusHook (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:280:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:94:7)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:120:9)
    at run (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\run.js:70:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapterInit.js:122:21)
    at jestAdapter (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-circus\build\legacy-code-todo-rewrite\jestAdapter.js:79:19)
    at runTestInternal (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:367:16)
    at runTest (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\runTest.js:444:34) 
    at Object.worker (C:\Users\manuchadha\OneDrive - Microsoft\Manu_Personal\leren\node_modules\jest-runner\build\testWorker.js:106:12)

Node.js v18.16.1
 FAIL  test/api.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                               
    Jest worker encountered 4 child process exceptions, exceeding retry limit                                                  
                                                                                                                               
      at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:181:21)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are two problem is in you code
As I can see on your error message.

You are try to access MongoDB URL but not able to find it.
and second you :
You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From test/api.test.js.

Comment: sorry but that doesn't help much